# Pass service result to other controller

Tags: angularjs, local-storage

I am calling `getLanguageSpecificData(LangCode)` service from home controller and saving the data into `localStorage`. On Home page there are `Language` links, if user click on **English** then it will redirect to a second template. But the problem is that still home controller `getLanguageSpecificData(LangCode)` service is not completed its execution.So in second Controller when I am trying to get result from `localStorage` it is incorrect(not updated).
So can you please tell which is better approach in this situation ?

HomeController code :

```
app.controller('homeController',function($scope,$localStorage,$appService){     
    $scope.loadlanguagefile = function(langcode){           
        $troubleshootingService.getLanguageSpecificData(LangCode).then(function(responce){
            $localStorage.data = responce.data;
        });         
    }
});
```

'loadlanguagefile' function is called when user click on Enlgish link and app is redirect to second template. here is secondController code :

```
app.controller('secondController',function($scope,$localStorage){
    $scope.data = $localStorage.data;
});
```

Comment: Please add some code, so that we can check it.

Answer (score 0):

As per my suggestion, you should use **callback function** to do your need full, when the function is called make the **English** click *disable* , and if your result is successful the make that **enable**. It will be something like this:

```
   getLanguageSpecificData(LangCode,callback:(dataToReturn:any)=>void):any{
     //logic  here to get data to return

     callback(dataToReturn);
    }
```

For calling this method -

1- before calling the method make English click disable.

2- then call the method-

```
  getLanguageSpecificData(imputLangCode,(result)=>{

      //logic for data modification
      //logic to enable English click

    });
```

3- Enable the English click inside the call of the method.

Comment: thanks for your help.problem is when user click on 'English' link then I wrote redirect page code : href ='#/secondTemplate' in home html page.can we write redirect code in 'homeController' after 'getLanguageSpecificData' service successfully called.

Comment: you wont need that , if you disable English link , until the `getLanguageSpecificData` would not return. And yes technically you can redirect code to any controller after service call success .